# Which calls need an access token in ActiveCollab v5 API

Tags: google-apps-script, activecollab

I'm playing with Google Apps Script utilizing the ActiveCollab HTTPS API as a way to link Google Forms to specific projects. I can't figure out where to use the access token in the HTTP request when creating a Task in a project.

Maybe I'm missing it, [but which API calls in the documentation](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html) require the access token as part of the POST request?

The most basic POST request I've sent was:

```
var token = // token from authentication

{
  "name": "Test task",
  "token": token
}
```

...and it returned a 401 error, saying I wasn't authenticated.

So, I tried:

```
var token = // token from authentication

{
  "name": "Test task",
  "username": // my username,
  "password": // my password,
  "token": token
}
```

...with the same result. So, which calls require a `token` and does the token go in the POST payload? Or should it be in the POST options?

**Update 3/10/2016**

I have added the `Authorization` parameter to the `POST` request and am now receiving an invalid token error in the response. I've cleared my cache and reauthorized successfully. My test function is below.

```
function postTicket() {

  // Retrieve the stored token after a successful authorization
  var token = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("token");

  var data = {
    "name": "Testing task"
  }

  var headers = { 
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(data)
  }

  try {
    var url = BASE_URL + "/projects/8/tasks";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.stringify(json)

    Logger.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

The logged error is:

> returned code
>   500.{"type":"ActiveCollab\Authentication\Exception\InvalidTokenException","message":"Authorization
>   token is not valid","code":0

Comment: Yea took a look at the docs. No mention where in the request to put the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, but after checking [Active Collab SDK code](https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk/blob/63401d46bfe2b54c1ad173d38a887fdf83e961dc/src/Client.php#L156-L164) i figured out, that we should use these headers:

```
var headers = { 
  'X-Angie-AuthApiToken': token
};
```

By using this code i'm allowed to create tasks via API.

Answer (score 0):

Token needs to be sent using `Authorization` HTTP header:

```
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_THAT_YOU_GOT_FROM_ACTIVE_COLLAB
```

This means that you need to send the token as part of request header, not payload. Please check the Google Apps documentation for details (I see that `fetch` has `headers` object as one of the arguments, so there is support for this type of interaction built into the platform).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I added the header and now I'm seeing an error saying the token is bad. Does it need to be encoded as a URI component? Or can I send it as a JS Object?

Comment: Or, do I need to be subscribed to the API in ActiveCollab itself?

Comment: The actual header appears to be {'X-Angie-AuthApiToken': token}. The token pattern you described doesn't work.